# Ambiguous behavior of setTimeout when used with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

I wanted to run an async method inside a promise for every x seconds until a specific condition is met and then call `resolve()` to resolve the promise. I tried it using two approaches(shown below). The second approach is devised using IIFE and is giving the correct results but in the first approach, the `setTimeout` method is running just once but according to the def. of `setTimeout` it should execute a callback indefinitely after a specified amount of time until `clearTimeout()` is called. Can anyone explain to me why am I not getting the desired output in the first approach?

**Approach 1**

```
function func2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params1).then((response) => {
                //    some code
                //    some code

                if (condition is met) {
                    return resolve()
                } else {
                    //    some code
                }
            })
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
function func2 () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (function func1() {
            client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params1).then((response) => {
                //    some code
                if (condition is met) {
                    return resolve()
                } else {
                    //    some code
                    setTimeout(func1, 1000)
                }
            })
        })()
    }
}
```

Comment: do you call `func2` in first approach where `// some code` goes?

Comment: in your second case a recursive call is happening and that makes your setTimeout works like setinterval

Comment: @skyboyer I am not calling func2 in those lines. I think I have confused `setInterval` with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` executes the function only once, i think you're looking for `setInterval()`. It works the same way, but in executes the function indefinitely unit `clearInterval()` is called on it.

This would be your function:

```js
function func2() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {

  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params1).then((response) => {
    //    some code
    //    some code

    if (condition is met) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      return resolve()
  } else {
    //    some code
  }
})
}, 1000)
})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with recursive functions

```
function waitForTimeline() {
   return client
       .get('statuses/user_timeline', params1)
       .then((response) => {
           if (condition is met) { return response }
           // In case the condition was not met, just call the same function
           // after a second
           return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
               setTimeout( () => {
                  waitForTimeline()
                      .then( resolve )
                      .catch( reject )
               }, 1000 );
           } );     
       }
};
```